# Architecture with Velocity templating

Tags: java, velocity

I would like to ask a couple of questions regarding use of Velocity templating engine just to make sure i am using is correclty.

There is a data model (deep object graph of models) that i want to access from the templates. I would really like, it seems to be the cleanest way as well, to have one template for each model: 
 PageModel           -> page.vm
 |--SectionModel     -> section.vm

Would it be appropriate to page.vm making a call to the custom wrapper of velocity engine and asking it to get a rendered string representation of the section.vm. The reason for it is that i want to have section.vm *not* sharing context variables set for page.vm.

The idea is that each template has its model being accessible over $model context variable. Each subtemplate is not being included with #parse directive but rather rendered into the host template (subtemplates also use their own $model attribute which is set to the submodels).

I hope that my explanation makes sense. Are there any performance drawbacks related to such design? My concern is that constantly creating Template objects and calling merge method to render them could turn out to become a performance hog.

thanks for your suggestions.